# Will the loaded class in 'method area' be unloaded by GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In hotspot jvm , in memory area there are heap and method area , and in method ,there are 'heap' and 'method area' etc. The object I `new` is set to heap, the classes, field , interface loaded by classloader is set to method area.

I guess gc shouldn't collect the class information which in method area. However an article in Chinese shows that `it does't mean gc wouldn't handle method area, it is just very few. When it happens, the constants and loaded class, field etc will be collected.`

I am doubtful whether it will happen. If yes, when?

(I want to figure it out because that i am studying a method hook strategy , if the loaded class will be collected by GC that I don't know when , the method I have hooked will fail, and load a new , unhooked one)

Answer (score 0):

> I am doubtful whether it will happen. If yes, when?

When a class is collected, everything associated with that class (including code in the PermGen/metaspace) is also collected.

A class is collected when there is no more references to that class.

If a class was loaded by a class loader, the class will only be cleaned when the class loader is unloaded.  If any instance of any class points to a class loader, every class in that class loader is still has a reference to it which is why many application never clean up these classes.

You can have classes e.g. generated class which are not associated with a class loader and these can die when they are no longer used.